# Rollback an old branch from master regardless of other branches pushed afterwards

Tags: git, gitlab

**First scenario :**

I have 3 branches that I worked on. Branch A, branch B, branch C.

I developped, tested and merged/pushed branch A to master. I delete branch A since it's merged to master.

A week later, branches B and C are tested and pushed to master. I delete B and C since they're merged to master.

Another week later, the boss comes in the office and says "A was a bad idea, I'd like to remove this.".
Obviously, he wants to remove A, but wants to keep B and C in the production.

How can I do this ? In this scenario, A is totally independant from B and C.

**Second scenario :**

This scenario is the same as the first scenario, except B and C rebased to master when A was merged to master.
Thus, they received new methods available thanks to A, and used them.

Now I wonder, how could we "remove" A without breaking B and C ?

To me the answer is "tests will tell what's wrong", but we don't have tests.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your boss wants to completely remove the changes introduced into `master` from the `A` branch, you should be able to get away with simply reverting the `A` merge commit in `master`.  Using `git revert` will introduce a new commit which effectively undoes everything which the original commit introduced.

```
git checkout master
git log
# find the SHA-1 hash of merge commit A (e.g. d82n93kd...)
git revert d82n93kd -m 1
```

Comment: So you're saying git revert will "remove" the merge, but every commits (which are not from A) after will still be there ?

Comment: @SteveChamaillard `git revert` actually adds a _new_ commit which does the mirror image of what merging `A` into `master` did.  It doesn't actually remove the merge commit, which will still be there, but functionally your branch should behave as if that merge never happened.

Comment: I think you will need to add `-m 1` to the revert command, which specifies the mainline to use for finding the diff. Otherwise the revert will fail due to reverting a merge without giving the -m option.

Answer (score 1):

For the **first scenario**: Find the hash of the merge commit for Branch A and do

```
git revert <hash>
```

The **second scenario** should work the same if you merged A into master, as the revert of the merge commit will undo the changes, and merging B and C to master has not brought in the changes again.

You can however also undo every commit in branch A, by doing `git revert` with each of the hashes. EDIT: Keep in mind to do the reverts of the single commits in reverse order, i.e. starting with the newest.

Comment: So, with no-ff option when merging, I can't revert individual commits, while without no-ff I can either revert the merge commit OR revert the hashes of commits from A individually ?

Comment: No, even with `--no-ff` you can revert the individual commits. That would only be impossible if you had done a "squashed merge", which would put all the changes into a single commit. But then you could just revert this single commit, which is roughly equivalent to reverting the merge commit.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers already said, the **first scenario** can be solved with `git revert -m 1 <hash-of-merge>`. "-m 1" tells git which of the parents of the merge commit is the mainline and should NOT be reverted. You can see the parents using `git show <hash-of-merge>` which will give you output like "Merge:  ". If you want to keep the changes from  and all its parents you use "-m 1".

This will result in a new commit which simply undoes all changes done by branch A.

An alternative would be to use `git rebase` with the `--preserve-merges` option, which allows you to rewrite your history and remove that merge. This however will change your history which is not a good idea if that branch is already used by others (which is probable if it is your master).

Regarding your **second scenario** I'm quite sure it won't be possible without some manual work. Removing A will in every case remove the functions introduced by that branch and that will break the changes from B and C if they depend on those functions. So you can either remove the feature from A manually, leaving all functions which are still required. Or you do a revert of A as described above and afterwards manually add those functions again. Which option is better depends on how much of branch A should really be removed and how much should be kept.